# SQL Count with multiple criteria and conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a count statement in SQL2008 that returns instances where certain specific criteria is met, some of these conditionals.

Pseudocode example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table T
WHERE T.Value IN ('Value', 'Value2', 'Value3')
    AND IF T.Value = 'Value2'
    THEN T.Date must be between @Date1 AND @Date2
```

Is this possible in SQL Syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table T
WHERE T.Value IN ('Value', 'Value2', 'Value3')
    AND (
      (T.Value = 'Value2' AND
      T.Date between @Date1 AND @Date2)
      OR (T.Value <> 'Value2')
    )
```